# How many ways to draw consecutive fibonacci numbers from deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory

In a deck of cards there are 4 suits of 13 cards each.  If the face value of the aces is defined as 1 and the jack, queen, and king are 11, 12, and 13 respectively, then:

1)

What is the probability of drawing 2 cards from the deck whose face values add up to 13?

What is the probability of drawing 3 cards whose face values add up to 13?

Is there a way to generalize this to $k$ cards adding up to $n$?

2)

What is the probability of drawing 3 cards that are 3 consecutive Fibonacci numbers?

What is the probability of drawing 4 cards that are 4 consecutive Fibonacci numbers?

(For eg.: ace, ace, 2, 3 or 3, 5, 8, 13.  But the order in which they are drawn is not important!)

Is there a way to generalize this to $k$ cards that are $k$ consecutive Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Seens to be important information missing... the most important piece is, Are we drawing with or without replacement?  That is a big deal!

Comment: from what I can tell, you may be able to find a general formula, but it is not an easy calculation.  As far as the first questions regarding 2 and 3 cards, these are really just straight up probability problems.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Without replacement.  What do you mean "straight up probability problems"?

Comment: was this helpful at all?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Yes I think so.  I am studying it.

Comment: Use the same principles: For 2 consecutive Fibonacci numbers you can have (1,1),(1,2),(2,3),...,(8,K).  The number of ways for each pair is 2 since (1,2)=(2,1), but for (1,1) there is only one way.  So the probability for 2 is $5\cdot{\frac{16}{52\cdot51}}+\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{51}$

Comment: for the 3 consecutive fibonacci numbers, you can have (1,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,3,5),(3,5,8),and (5,8,K).  For the last  3-tuples, there are 3! ways of combining them but for (1,1,2) there are only 3...  It may be easier to find a general theorem for the second part of your question because the maximum number you can have is |(1,1,2,3,5,8,K)|=7, and the only k-tuple that has repeating numbers is the first, i.e., (1,1,2,...,n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generalization for the second part of your question; consecutive fibonacci numbers:
As above we have k-tuples that are unordered; so for example, 4 and 5 consecutive fibonacci numbers can be
$$(2,3,5,8)$$and$$(1,1,2,3,5)$$
There will always be the k-tuple that has $(1,1,...)$ in it as well.  We also know that the maximum number k can be is 7, since
$$(1,1,2,3,5,8,K)$$is the longest sequence of fibonacci numbers we can draw from a deck of cards

In general, for each k-tuple, there are $(7-k)$ k-tuples with $k$ distinct digits and one k-tuple with $(k-1)$ distinct digits (the k-tuple with two 1's).  There are also $k!$ different ways of ordering the k-tuples and $(k-1)!$ ways of ordering the single $(1,1,...)$ k-tuple.  Thus, we can generalize the probability as such;
$$P(\text{sequence of k fibonacci numbers})=(7-k)\cdot{k!}\cdot\frac{4^k}{P(52,k)}+(k-1)!\cdot{\frac{4^{(k-1)}\cdot3}{P(52,k)}}$$
$$=\frac{(k-1)!\cdot{4^{k-1}}}{P(52,k)}\cdot[(3+28k-4k^2)]$$

Where $P(n,k)$ represents the permutation $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you are just picking two cards and there is not much to it.  You have in this case, 6 different ways to produce 13;
$$(1,Q),(2,J),(3,10),(4,9),(5,8),(6,7)$$
Since $$(1,Q)=(Q,1)$$we have 2 ways of drawing each of them.  There are 4 cards of each number/face, so the probability of drawing two cards with replacement that add up to 13 is
$$6\cdot{2}\cdot{\frac{4\cdot{4}}{52\cdot{52}}}=.071$$
Without replacement it is just
$$6\cdot{2}\cdot{\frac{4\cdot{4}}{52\cdot{51}}}=.0724$$
For 3 cards it's a little more work, but it is the same technique.  THe ways of having 3 cards add up to 13 are as follows;
$$(1,1,J),(1,2,10),(1,3,9),(1,4,8),(1,5,7),(1,6,6)$$
$$(2,2,9),(2,3,8),(2,4,7),(2,5,6)$$
$$(3,3,7),(3,4,6),(3,5,5)$$
$$(4,4,5)$$
Now instead of two different ways for each 3-tuple, we have a couple of choices:  For the 3-tuples with 3 distinct digits, there are 3! different ways of selecting them, and for the 3 tuples with 2 distinct digits (i.e., $(1,1,J)$), there are $\frac{3!}{2!\cdot{1!}}=3$ ways of selecting.
So there are 8 different 3-tuples with 3 distinct digits and 6 different 3-tuples with 2 distinct digits so the probability of drawing 3 cards with replacement that sum to 13 is
$$8\cdot{6}\cdot{\frac{4^3}{52^3}}+6\cdot{3}\cdot{\frac{4^2\cdot{3}}{52^3}}=.028$$
Without replacement it is just
$$8\cdot{6}\cdot{\frac{4^3}{52\cdot{51}\cdot{50}}}+6\cdot{3}\cdot{\frac{4^2\cdot{3}}{52\cdot{51}\cdot{50}}}=.0297$$

Use the same general principles to work out your consecutive Fibonacci sequences.